# Why is reverse KL more suited for data generation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, kullback-leibler, gan, divergence

Here goes a first question! In a paper I'm reading in the context of GAN's (WGAN in particular) I came across the following quote when the authors discuss KL divergence:

> while maximum likelihood incentivises model distributions under which the data from the empirical distribution is likely, data generation might be more interested in the reverse: model distributions which produce data that is likely under the empirical distribution

I have no clue how to interpret that statement. I intuitively understand KL divergence. I understand it is asymmetric so, $KL(P_{\theta_*}, P_{\theta}) \neq KL(P_{\theta},P_{\theta_*})$, where the true parameter is $\theta_*$ and the data comes  from $P_{\theta_*}$. I understand that I can minimise $KL(P_{\theta_*}, P_{\theta})$ w.r.t. $\theta$ because it is equivalent to minimising $E_{\theta_*}(ln(p_{\theta}(x)))$ w.r.t $\theta$ and I can estimate $E_{\theta_*}(ln(p_{\theta}(x)))$ using the LLN. Intuitively I think this means finding the parameter value that makes the data most likely.

But I feel like my way of looking at KL divergence is also limiting my understanding. How would I go about interpreting what the quote called "the reverse": $KL(P_{\theta}, P_{\theta_*})$. The only reason I was able to estimate $E_{\theta_*}(ln(p_{\theta}(x)))$ is because my data comes from the "true" distribution parametrised by $\theta_*$. I have no way of calculating $E_{\theta}(ln(p_{\theta_*}(x)))$ because I don't know $\theta_*$, so I can't use my statistical hammer (LLN).

I would appreciate any help.

Link to the paper (quote @ middle page 5):

https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.02210

Niels

Comment: Welcome to Machine Learning: " 'machine learning is statistics minus any checking of models and assumptions'. -- Brian D. Ripley (about the difference between machine learning and statistics) useR! 2004, Vienna (May 2004)".  I would suspect that this is just wishy washy pseudo-stats.  Perhaps you can link to the paper and give further context

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I included it in the question. This paper :https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02780.pdf also included reverse KL, but here I also cannot figure it out.

Comment: I can't understand the comment but would suggest looking at the referred article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05101.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll check it out!